# Is ref const X the same as const ref X in D?

Tags: constants, d

Quite recently it has been discussed here how strange `const` is in D in terms of placement (right or left of function name etc.).

Now I wonder, if `ref const X` the same as `const ref X` in function parameter?

both versions compile in my test project but I'd like a confirmation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order only matters if you need to use parens.

```
void foo(ref const int* x) {...}
```

is the same as

```
void foo(const ref int* x) {...}
```

However, if you want `const(int)*`, then you're going to have to do

```
void foo(ref const(int)* x) {...}
```

because then there's no way to put the `ref` to the right of the `const` with the parens there.

The only case that I'm aware of where the order of attributes matters on a parameter, other genres of variables, or a return type when it's not syntax issue is with `auto ref`, because `auto ref` is essentially an attribute made up of two words rather than being two separate attributes both affecting the symbol. In all other cases, the order shouldn't matter. And the order doesn't matter on function attributes either. It's just the whole left-hand side vs right-hand side of the function signature bit that's an ordering issue.

Comment: Ok thanks! Does it make sense to say e.g. `const ref(int)[]` ? Because that's the only thing you haven't considered ;-)

Comment: @BindersLachel No, that doesn't work. As I said, you can't put the `ref` on the right-hand side because of the parens. They go with `const`, not `ref`.